# How to get rid of gap between input text and button on all devices?

Tags: html, css

I've an `input text field` and a `button` next to each other.

The problem is that there is a gap between this two elements.

> I can fix this by changing the `margin-bottom` of the button to `5px`.

But maybe there is a more clever way of fixing this? As I need both of them to be next to each other on every device.

Some times the button goes down the input text.

[image]

[image]

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RzPqLw

Comment: you can consider `white-space: nowrap;` on the container and `vertical-align:top` on the elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap both the `input` and `button` with a div and set its `display` to `flex`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex input {
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container margin-top10 margin-bottom5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
      <h1 class="text-center my_title">
        Tu carrito de compras
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center">
      <table class="table my_custom_table">
        <thead class="my_custom_thead">
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">
              Tus items
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- MOSTRAR SAMPLE_ITEMS IN CART_DETAIL -->
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="cart_item.product.get_absolute_url"><img src="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/sample_images/Artboard_1.png" alt="" class="float-left rounded" width="90" height="90"></a>
            </td>
            <td class="text-left">
              <p class="margin-bottom0"><b>Sobre con muestras</b></p>
              <p class="margin-top0 margin-bottom0">Cantidad: 5 stickers</p>
              <p class="margin-top0 margin-bottom0">Tamaño: varios</p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p>S/5

                <a href="/carrito_de_compras/full_remove_sample/163/" class="custom_icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt custom_icon"></i></a>
              </p>
            </td>
            <td></td>

          </tr>



        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center">

      <table class="table my_custom_table">

        <thead class="my_custom_thead">

          <tr>
            <th>
              Checkout
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tboyd>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Por favor, revise su Carrito de Compras antes de proceder con el pago de la orden
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-left">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  Total: S/5<br> Costo de envío: S/15<br> Descuento: <span class="savings"><b>S/0</b></span><br> A pagar: <strong>S/20</strong><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <br>
                  <div class="flex">
                    <input type="text" id="user_cupon" style="display: inline-block; height: 36px;" placeholder="Ingrese cupón">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="cuponButton" style="display: inline-block; height: 35px;">Enviar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <td class="text-left">
              <b>Dirección de envío:</b>
              <select type="text" id="ShippingAddress">
                <option value="Urb. La Merced Mz.G Lot.32" selected>
                  Urb. La Merced Mz.G Lot.32</option>
                <option value="">
                </option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="bg-buttons margin-top3 padding-top6 padding-bottom3">






              </div>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </tboyd>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Updated the snippet to add some margin between the two

Comment: ty. Works great. Is there a way to put some spacing between the input and the button, with the flex class the appear inline (as desidered) but without space between each other.

Comment: You can give either of the elements some `margin`. I've updated the above snippet

Comment: You've added some space using pixels, I've been recommended to add it using %, what is your take on this recomendation? ty.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use %? I can understand using % to create your layout and set the size of the containers. I don't see any harm in using pixels to set apart two elements

Comment: No, no specific reason, just asking. I was told that for a better response on each device to use %, and with text size erm.

Comment: And I concur with the same as I mentioned in my previous comment that it's perfect for creating a layout and spacing out the containers which will let you achieve an adaptive design (not responsive, there's a minor difference). I've noticed that you're already using Bootstrap. Why not take its leverage to maintain the responsiveness!

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` to the input and `float: right;` to the button.